# Angularjs CRUD delete issue (GET called in DELETE method)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to consume my spring rest service using angularjs client following this [link](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-angularjs-crud-application-using-ngresource/)

Create,update and read parts are working. When I try to delete, its showing this error.

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action
>   `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array
>   (Request: GET http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/employee)

Why i am getting GET request in DELETE method?

employee_service.js

```
'use strict';

App.factory('Employee', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
            'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/employee/:id', 
            {id: '@employeeId'},
            {
                update: {
                      method: 'PUT' 
                }

            }
    );
}]);
```

employee_controller.js

```
'use strict';

App.controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'Employee', function($scope, Employee) {
          var self = this;
          self.employee= new Employee();

          self.employees=[];

          self.fetchAllEmployees = function(){
              self.employees = Employee.query();
          };

          self.createEmployee = function(){
              self.employee.$save(function(){
                  self.fetchAllEmployees();
              });
          };

          self.updateEmployee = function(){
              self.employee.$update(function(){
                  self.fetchAllEmployees();
              });
          };

         self.deleteEmployee = function(identity){
             var employee = Employee.get({employeeId:identity}, function() {
                 employee.$delete(function(){
                      console.log('Deleting employee with id ', identity);
                      self.fetchAllEmployees();
                  });
             });
          };

          self.fetchAllEmployees();

          self.submit = function() {
              if(self.employee.employeeId==null){
                  console.log('Saving New Employee', self.employee);    
                  self.createEmployee();
              }else{
                  console.log('Updating employee with id ', self.employee.employeeId);
                  self.updateEmployee();
                  console.log('Employee updated with id ', self.employee.employeeId);
              }
              self.reset();
          };

          self.edit = function(employeeId){
              console.log('id to be edited', employeeId);
              for(var i = 0; i < self.employees.length; i++){
                  if(self.employees[i].employeeId === employeeId) {
                     self.employee = angular.copy(self.employees[i]);
                     break;
                  }
              }
          };

          self.remove = function(employeeId){
              console.log('id to be deleted', employeeId);
              if(self.employee.employeeId === employeeId) {//If it is the one shown on screen, reset screen
                 self.reset();
              }
              self.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
          };


          self.reset = function(){
              self.employee= new Employee();
              $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
          };

      }]);
```

Comment: please someone help me.

Comment: Sounds like your backend is returning an array for the `.get` request. Nothing to do with `DELETE`. Check the response data for `http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/employee/someEmployeeId`

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Phil the url will return employee details(id,firstname,lastname and age) of the employeeId.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Pick a valid employee ID (let's say it's "1") and use `curl` or similar to request `http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/employee/1`. If the response starts with `[` and not `{`, then it is returning an array where Angular is expecting an object

Comment: yeah its returning with {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be when you call `Employee.get({employeeId:identity}, ...)` prior to deleting the employee. This will load the employee before deletion and it will do a GET request on `'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/employee/:id'`.

For this query to work properly, you need to provide `id`, which you haven't done, so it might just be leaving out that part of the URL. You provided `employeeId`, which is only used for mapping the id parameter to the `Employee` objects. Try replacing the query above with `{id: identity}`.

Comment: @Phil so i have got some other issue as you suggested in the first comment?

Comment: @Phil I think that is only for mapping to the `Employee.employeeId` property.

Comment: @lyschoening you are correct. From the documentation ~ *"If the parameter value is prefixed with `@`, then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the `data` object (provided when calling a **"non-GET"** action method)."*